# Casting Object to List without SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, list, swt, checkstyle, tableviewer

I am trying to use the return type of [`TableViewers getInput()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TableViewer.html) method to be cast to `List<?>`. The unchecked type NIGHTMARE takes over and adds warnings.

I cannot use SuppressWarnings to hide the warning because Checkstyle settings on this source prohit:

1. Warnings and
2. the Suppression of Warnings.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: an why can't you change the return type to List?

Comment: @sidgate Are you familiar with `TableViewer`? http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html

Comment: You can cast to `List`, but not to `List<Something>`. The former is a checked cast. Way around this: a) change Checkstyle setting; b) if that's prohibited, fire the author of Checkstyle settings, then return to a) :-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm very much in favor of your Checkstyle solution :D

Comment: Have you already tried suppressing Checkstyle itself? `//CHECKSTYLE:OFF` is the standard way. But your "guy" may have disabled even that.

Comment: Have you tried `List<?> list = (List<?>) tblViewer.getInput();`? I'm not getting any warnings with that ... %-/

Comment: I am having the same problem and I don't like to suppress warnings.  If I would use `TableViewer`s input just to read its contents `List< ? > viewerInput = (List< ? >)viewer.getInput();` would be sufficient. But I want to put/remove objects, so I need to cast `viewerInput` to ``List<RequiredClass>`. How to get rid of the warnings now?